# Filter button winform execution event problem

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filtering

i have a textbox & and a button to filter data in my datagridview box, But i have also given a condition that if the form is under editing mode it should not allow filter.

Now the problem is once i click add new record button & even if i save the record, it always shows exception as the form is is editing mode can't filter.

```
Private Sub AddnewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddnewButton.Click
    'MsgBox("you preseed add new button")
    Try
        With AddnewButton
            If .Text = "Add New Record" Then
                MSdiesBindingSource.AddNew()
                .Text = "Cancel"
            Else
                RefreshData()
                MSdiesDataGridView.ClearSelection()
                .Text = "Add New Record"
            End If

        End With
        With Size_in_mgTextBox
            If (.CanSelect) Then
                .Text = String.Empty
                .Select()
            End If
        End With

        IsAddNewRecordInProgress = Convert.ToBoolean(AddnewButton.Text = "Cancel")


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occured: " & ex.Message.ToString().ToString(),
              MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add new Record Failed")
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub RefreshData()
    Try
        'Me.MSdiesBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
        MSdiesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TrialdatabaseDataSet.MSdies)
        MSdiesBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Refresh Data Error!")
    End Try


End Sub
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    'MsgBox("you preseed add new button")
    Try
        Dim result As DialogResult
        result = MessageBox.Show("Confirm Save?", "Save Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
            Validate()
            MSdiesBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TrialdatabaseDataSet)
            MessageBox.Show("The record Has been saved",
                   "Save Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            RefreshData()
            AddnewButton.Text = "Add New Record"
        Else
            ' Exit Sub
            Return
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Save Data Failed: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                   "Save Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub AlertWarningMessage()
    'Do not allow search while addign record
    MsgBox("The Search Function Is Disabled While Adding New Record",
            MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Find Record")
End Sub

Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status"
    If IsAddNewRecordInProgress = True Then
        AlertWarningMessage()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(KeywordTextBox.Text) Then
        SearchInAccessDatabase(KeywordTextBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"))
    Else
        RefreshData()
        Return
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not for us to just read through your code, hoping to see something wrong. You need to actually debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, examining the state before and after each step to see whether it behaves as you expect. If it doesn't then you have found an issue and you can investigate that specifically. If you still need our help, you can provide ALL the relevant information. If it does behave as you expect but doesn't produce the desired result then your expectations are wrong, so you need to reevaluate them.

Comment: Need to set `IsAddNewRecordInProgress` to `False` in the Save button click event?

Comment: This is the problem when you use different boolean conditions to track things - you toggle your button text back and forth, but you don't do the same with your boolean.. You remembered to set the button text back to "Add new" when you save, but you forgot to do the same with the boolean. Perhaps you should make one method that does these two things (chenge button text, change boolean) and call it, so you arent having to do a pair of things all the time